# Django admin и кастомные формы создания и редактирования объекта

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Имеется: Django 4.2 модель объекта и две формы на базе `forms.ModelForm` не понимаю как сделать так что бы в админке при создании объекта была одна форма, а при его редактировании другая??

**forms.py**

```py
class CreateUserCertficateFrom(forms.ModelForm):
    """Base user creation form"""

    class Meta:
        model = InfoSeqUserCertficateModel
        fields = [
            'user_firstname',
            'user_lastname',
            'user_login',
        ]


class EditUserCertficateFrom(forms.ModelForm):
    """Base user change form"""

    class Meta:
        model = InfoSeqUserCertficateModel
        fields = [
            'user_firstname',
            'user_lastname',
            'user_login',
            'user_slug',
            'password1',
            'password2',
            'certificate',
        ]
```

**admin.py**

```py
@admin.register(InfoSeqUserCertficateModel)
class UserCertficateAdminModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """"""

    form = CreateUserCertficateFrom
    change_form = EditUserCertficateFrom

    def get_queryset(self, request: HttpRequest) -> QuerySet[Any]:
        """"""

        UserCertification._manager()
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        return qs
```